# Criando menu para linkar div

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Tenho um link:

```
<li><a href="#schedule">Programação</a></li>
```

Que redireciona para a div:

```
<div class="schedule" id="schedule">
    <h1>Programação</h1>
</div>
```

No firefox e no Edge funciona perfeitamente, quando observo o link na barra de status do navegador parece assim:

```
meusite.com/#schedule
```

Mas no Chrome não funciona o link, a barra de status, a '/' não aparece e fica assim:

```
meusite.com#schedule
```

O que posso fazer para o Chrome funcione?

Esse site eu fiz já faz uns 3 anos e o cliente nunca me relatou o erro, agora ele me procurou para solicitar a correção. Será que foi alguma atualização do Chrome? Eu já testei em vários navegadores Chrome em diversos dispositivos e o problema persiste.

Comment: Testei no Chrome e funcionou perfeitamente. O código acima está correto. Pode ser que outra coisa ou script esteja interferindo no funcionamento do mesmo. Olhe no console do Chrome para ver se não existe algum erro de script.

Comment: Rafael, podes criar um exemplo no jsFiddle que não funcione para ti?

Comment: Sergio, criei no jsFiddler, o link é https://jsfiddle.net/0unyvtk3/#&togetherjs=lNznulMvl3, como é a primeira vez que utilizo não se se fiz correto, mas tá lá.. 
Obrigado pela Atenção